¿Modificar ventana de archivo .txt?
Hice un bat que me crea un archivo txt con ciertas líneas de texto y cuando se ejecuta el archivo de texto es de tamaño grande (no me refiero al tamaño de la consola cmd)... Por favor que comando puedo agregarle para que al abrirse ese archivo .txt tenga un tamaño especifico osea más pequeño
Echo. > "%TEMP%\s.txt"

echo me gustan todos> "%TEMP%\s.txt"

echo los animales>> "%TEMP%\s.txt"

echo menos los>> "%TEMP%\s.txt"

echo SAPOS>> "%TEMP%\s.txt"

START "" "%TEMP%\s.txt"

exit


Ejecutando el BAT que propones no veo nada que me encaje con el "tamaño grande" del que hablas. El comando START lanza el "Bloc de notas" en el que se ve el texto trasladado al archivo s.txt en un tamaño absolutamente normal, o eso me parece a mí.

Si quieres que el bloc de notas se abra con un tamaño de ventana más pequeño basta con que lo ejecutes una vez, incluso en vacío, y controles el tamaño de la ventana con el cursor. Luego lo cierras y se quedará ese tamaño asociado hasta que vuelvas a cambiarlo
